# Creating class and calculating a value in Python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner. Lets go!! .. I have the class:

```
class Recision
  def __init__(self, salary, month)
    self.salary = salary
    self.month  = month
```

*Here begins my doubt:
*
I need to create a method that does the following: 
`var total = (salary / 12) * month`
I tried:

```
     return (self.salary / 12) * self.month

   def calc_recision(self):
     calc = Recision(12000, 5)
     print(calc.total)
```

Please how do I do this, I have tried several alternatives

Comment: Please, provide your whole code and fix it. You have several syntax issues.

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych  tks

Comment: Your function `calc_recision` should return `(self.salary/12)*self.month` - then in your `__init__` you can write `self.total = self.calc_recision()`

Comment: @oskros Then you'll have an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot write a comment because I am fairly new but is this one "sequence" of code? You have a return in Your constructor (the init method). Calling Recision creates an object, and cannot have a return. Instead make a new method (as You did)

```
def calc_recision(self):
    return (self.salary / 12) * self.month
```

Down, at the end of you file create a new object and give it salary and month numbers and do `print(name_of_my_object.calc_recision())`.
Hope this helps and works (didnt use Python in a long time).
Example:

```
class Recision:
  def __init__(self, salary, month)
    self.salary = salary
    self.month  = month
  def calc_recision(self):
    return (self.salary / 12) * self.month

test = Recision(100, 2)
print(test.calc_recision())
```

Feel free to ask question and let me know if it works.

Comment: Although what you wrote is right, please remember the OP looks for a property named `total` (`calc.total`)

Answer (score 0):

As said in some comments before the best course of action is to create a variable already in the class init function

```
class Recision:
  def __init__(self, salary, month):
    self.salary = salary
    self.month  = month
    self.total = (salary / 12) * month
```

not calling more functions can be helpful if you want to reduce the run time of your program, but you also have to think (when you will create classes with hundreds of variables) if you need that data to be stored in your computer.